# Exception when using UDT in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a user defined type in spark sql, but I receive: 
com.ubs.ged.risk.stdout.spark.ExamplePointUDT cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType even when using their example. Has anyone made this work?

My code:

```
test("udt serialisation") {
    val points = Seq(new ExamplePoint(1.3, 1.6), new ExamplePoint(1.3, 1.8))
    val df = SparkContextForStdout.context.parallelize(points).toDF()
}

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[ExamplePointUDT]) 
case class ExamplePoint(val x: Double, val y: Double)

/**
 * User-defined type for [[ExamplePoint]].
 */
class ExamplePointUDT extends UserDefinedType[ExamplePoint] {

  override def sqlType: DataType = ArrayType(DoubleType, false)

  override def pyUDT: String = "pyspark.sql.tests.ExamplePointUDT"

  override def serialize(obj: Any): Seq[Double] = {
    obj match {
      case p: ExamplePoint =>
        Seq(p.x, p.y)
    }
  }

  override def deserialize(datum: Any): ExamplePoint = {
    datum match {
      case values: Seq[_] =>
        val xy = values.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]]
        assert(xy.length == 2)
        new ExamplePoint(xy(0), xy(1))
      case values: util.ArrayList[_] =>
        val xy = values.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[Double]].asScala
        new ExamplePoint(xy(0), xy(1))
    }
  }

  override def userClass: Class[ExamplePoint] = classOf[ExamplePoint]

}
```

The usefull stackstrace is this:

```
com.ubs.ged.risk.stdout.spark.ExamplePointUDT cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ubs.ged.risk.stdout.spark.ExamplePointUDT cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLContext.scala:254)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the UDT needs to be used inside of another class to work (as the type of a field). One solution to use it directly is to wrap it into a Tuple1:

```
  test("udt serialisation") {
    val points = Seq(new Tuple1(new ExamplePoint(1.3, 1.6)), new Tuple1(new ExamplePoint(1.3, 1.8)))
    val df = SparkContextForStdout.context.parallelize(points).toDF()
    df.collect().foreach(println(_))
  }
```